# Neo4j Active Node : how to use default_scope like active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Is there any way I can use default scope like active record?

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope

Or any other with which I can exclude nodes from any query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[neo4jrb](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) does not yet support a default scope. There is already an [open issue](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/807) for that.

If you are using the Enterprise Edition of neo4j, you can create [custom user roles](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/subgraph-access-control/) that are configured to have access to specific [procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/extending-neo4j/procedures/). A neo4j user assigned a given custom role is therefore only able to do whatever that role's procedures permit.